# Is the Alternate Ubuntu installer still required for LVM or Software RAID setup?

Tags: installation, raid, lvm, alternate

Over the past 5 years, I have been setting up Ubuntu servers using the Alternate installer. I need to provision a new server today, and I'm curious if the Alternate CD is still the only way to setup LVM/RAID at installation time. I'm my limited experience with Red Hat Enterprise Linux, I noticed it's single installer configures LVM automatically. Has Ubuntu's installer, at least the standard "Server" installer, added support for LVM/RAID, or is the Alternate installer still required for that kind of server setup?

http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/12.04.1/release/

> Alternate install CD
>
> The alternate install CD allows you to perform certain specialist
>   installations of Ubuntu. It provides for the following situations:
>
> - setting up automated deployments;
> - upgrading from older installations without network access;
> - **LVM and/or RAID partitioning;**
> - installs on systems with less than about 384MiB of RAM (although note that
>     low-memory systems may not be able to run a full desktop environment
>     reasonably).

LVM has always been fundamental for our server needs, so I'm surprised if it is still not considered a server-worthy feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu Server image has LVM and RAID, I think since 9.10. Go for the manual option at partitioning, you'll find it there.

If you want to have an Ubuntu Desktop on RAID/LVM, then you still need the Alternate image

Comment: I started with Ubuntu 6.06, so it's very likely I missed it when it was added, and I guess I never realized the Alternate wording quoted above was in contrast to LVM w/ desktop Ubuntu. I'll give the Server image a try now.